# How to match those numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of numbers, for example:

10001234
10002345

Now I have a number, which should be matched against all of those numbers inside the array. The number could either be 10001234 (which would be easy to match), but it could also be 100001234 (4 zeros instead of 3) or 101234 (one zero instead of 3) for example. Any combination could be possible. The only fixed part is the 1234 at the end.

I cant get the last 4 chars, because it can also be 3 or 5 or 6 ..., like 1000123456.

Whats a good way to match that? Maybe its easy and I dont see the wood for the trees :D.

Thanks!

Comment: Surprise Surprise.. You have got `\d` in regex which matches any digit. And added to that you have quantifiers, that can help you match a sequence of them.

Comment: [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)

Comment: always first number is one?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that, but if you have an idea to make it work with 2 as well, itll be fine.

Comment: What you want to achieve exact?

Comment: If you want the last 4 chars, you could always do substr($number, -4, 4).

Comment: you've not really described the pattern for the numbers very well. This is probably why you're struggling to come up with a regex for them, but it also means that we won't be likely to come up with a good answer either. In addition, it's not clear what output you're looking for: Are you hoping for a true/false result to say "this number matches the pattern" or "this one doesn't"? Or are you looking to extract a portion of the string to work with? Please edit the question to include more detail on these points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if always the first number is one you can use this

```
$Num=1000436346;
echo(int)ltrim($Num."","1");
```

output:

```
436346
```

Comment: +1. a sneaky approach! I like it. Note that this can be expanded to check for additional digits by adding them to the second param of `ltrim()`. Just don't include `0` and you'll be fine, as long as there is at least one zero between the prefix and the main number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number % 10000
```

Will return the remainder of dividing a number by 10000. Meaning, the last four digits.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make the criteria for the match very clear. However, I'll give it a go.

First, my assumptions:

- The number always starts with a `1` followed by an unknown number of `0`s.
- After that, we have a sequence of digits which could be anything (but presumably not starting with zero?), which you want to extract from the string?

Given the above, we can formulate an expression fairly easily:

```
$input='10002345';
if(preg_match('/10+(\d+)/',$input,$matches)) {
     $output = $matches[1];
}
```

`$output` now contains the second part of the number -- ie `2345`.

If you need to match more than just a leading `1`, you can replace that in the expression with `\d` to match any digit. And add a plus sign after it to allow more than one digit here (although we're still relying on there being at least one zero between the first part of the number and the second).

```
$input='10002345';
if(preg_match('/\d+0+(\d+)/',$input,$matches)) {
     $output = $matches[1];
}
```